# Developing with twitter API

Tags: c#, twitter

I am very new to C# and i wish to sharpen my skills with some sort of projects. I want to create a small project using the twitter api (Search), but I'm wondering what the steps are, do i import the class i wish to use ?. I just want a breakdown of how i go about using the API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that, you use the [LinqToTwitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/) from [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/linqtotwitter).

[AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) (a cloud hosting company) has a **small Twitter project** with Twitter and RavenDB in youtube, that you could easily follow up...

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmP5wG3_cxk

instead of saving tweets to the database, just use `Console.WriteLine()` and have some fun.

That can let you start with Twitter and C#...